# Funcationality and readability of if, else if, else statements

Tags: java, if-statement

Not exactly how to word the title but the general question is comparing these two blocks of code. The first is the original and the second is the one that would replace it.

Does this actually improve the code, it's efficiency or would it only improve readability? I don't believe they are functionally different, unless I am missing something.

**1ST:**

```
    if(stl1YVal < stl2YVal){
        return -1;
    }else if(stl1YVal > stl2YVal){
        return 1;
    }else{
        if(stl1XVal < stl2XVal){
            return -1;
        }else if(stl1XVal > stl2XVal){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**2ND:**

```
    if(stl1YVal < stl2YVal || stl1XVal < stl2XVal){
        return -1;
    }else if(stl1YVal > stl2YVal || stl1XVal > stl2XVal){
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
```

Edit: I am putting the entire method in so that it may make a little more sense to people... If people have answers/solutions to make it more readable and functional (since it seems the second one is not equivalent) that would be much appreciated.

(They are named stl because of the simple textline - I didn't name them)

```
public int compare(SimpleTextLine stl1, SimpleTextLine stl2){
        //0 -> stl1 and stl2 are equivalent, maintain current order
        //-1 -> stl1 comes before stl2
        //1 -> stl2 comes before stl1

        float stl1XVal = Math.round(stl1.getxLinePos());
        float stl1YVal = Math.round(stl1.getyLinePos());
        float stl2XVal = Math.round(stl2.getxLinePos());
        float stl2YVal = Math.round(stl2.getyLinePos());

        if(stl1YVal < stl2YVal){
            return -1;
        }else if(stl1YVal > stl2YVal){
            return 1;
        }else{
            if(stl1XVal < stl2XVal){
                return -1;
            }else if(stl1XVal > stl2XVal){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Always favor readability in these kinds of cases. Real efficiency is determined in completely different places than what kind of `if` statements you're using.

Comment: Your second solution is not functionally equivalent to the first one. Example: If `stl1YVal > stl2YVal` is true and `stl1XVal < stl2XVal` is true, the first solution returns 1, the second returns -1.

Comment: I  agree with @Kayaman. I'd rather deal with the second block. Efficiency/execution time would be highly dependent ton the language and environment and of no significance whatsoever unless it were being done a large number of times in a loop. even then, it would be a mistake to start 'optimising' without direct evidence (eg profiling).

Comment: `if (stl1YVal != stl2YVal) { return Integer.compare(stl1YVal, stl2YVal); } else { return Integer.compare(stl1XVal, stl2XVal); }` would be cleaner, IMO. But yes, what Kayaman and Bob said.

Comment: Actually Andys solution is functionally equivalent (and much nicer).

Comment: @AndyTurner [`Integer.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) is not guaranteed to return `-1` and `1`, just `<0` and `>0`. Perhaps that's what OP wants too, but `Integer.compare()` is not funationally equal to the shown code.

Comment: Or you can use Guava's `ComparisonChain.start().compare(stl1YVal, stl2YVal).compare(stl1XVal, stl2XVal).result()`.

Comment: @Andreas the method is a public int and it was intended to return a 1, -1, 0

Comment: If you want to talk about readability, you'd have to do something about those variable names....

Comment: @JonKiparsky this isn't mine originally, I inherited the project and part of my task was cleaning up code - so I am looking to document/make things more readable, but still be functional.

Comment: @Kayaman true. Then just replace `Integer.compare` with a conditional operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a "cleaner" version of the original code is one of these:

```java
// Option 1 (eliminating redundant 'else' clauses and nesting)
if (stl1YVal < stl2YVal)
    return -1;
if (stl1YVal > stl2YVal)
    return 1;
if (stl1XVal < stl2XVal)
    return -1;
if (stl1XVal > stl2XVal)
    return 1;
return 0;
```

```java
// Option 2 (using conditional ternary operator)
return (stl1YVal < stl2YVal ? -1 :
        stl1YVal > stl2YVal ? 1 :
        stl1XVal < stl2XVal ? -1 :
        stl1XVal > stl2XVal ? 1 : 0);
```

I think option 2 is great. Whether option 1 needs braces (`{}`) is up to your coding standard.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't believe they are functionally different, unless I am missing
>   something.

Please examine this simple test:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int y1=-1;y1<2;y1++){
            for(int y2=-1;y2<2;y2++){
                for(int x1=-1;x1<2;x1++){
                    for(int x2=-1;x2<2;x2++){
                        System.out.format(" %2d %2d %2d %2d ", y1, y2, x1, x2);
                        System.out.print(" ---- ");
                        int first = first( y1, y2, x1, x2);
                        int second = second( y1, y2, x1, x2);
                        System.out.format(" %2d %2d %b\n", first, second, first == second );
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static int first(int stl1YVal, int stl2YVal, int stl1XVal, int stl2XVal) {
        if (stl1YVal < stl2YVal) {
            return -1;
        } else if (stl1YVal > stl2YVal) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (stl1XVal < stl2XVal) {
                return -1;
            } else if (stl1XVal > stl2XVal) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int second(int stl1YVal, int stl2YVal, int stl1XVal, int stl2XVal) {
        if (stl1YVal < stl2YVal || stl1XVal < stl2XVal) {
            return -1;
        } else if (stl1YVal > stl2YVal || stl1XVal > stl2XVal) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

A result contains a few cases which are not equal, please examine the result:

```
-1 -1 -1 -1  ----   0  0 true
 -1 -1 -1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1 -1 -1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1 -1  0 -1  ----   1  1 true
 -1 -1  0  0  ----   0  0 true
 -1 -1  0  1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1 -1  1 -1  ----   1  1 true
 -1 -1  1  0  ----   1  1 true
 -1 -1  1  1  ----   0  0 true
 -1  0 -1 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  0 -1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  0 -1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  0  0 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  0  0  0  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  0  0  1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  0  1 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  0  1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  0  1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1 -1 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1 -1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1 -1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1  0 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1  0  0  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1  0  1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1  1 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1  1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
 -1  1  1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
  0 -1 -1 -1  ----   1  1 true
  0 -1 -1  0  ----   1 -1 false
  0 -1 -1  1  ----   1 -1 false
  0 -1  0 -1  ----   1  1 true
  0 -1  0  0  ----   1  1 true
  0 -1  0  1  ----   1 -1 false
  0 -1  1 -1  ----   1  1 true
  0 -1  1  0  ----   1  1 true
  0 -1  1  1  ----   1  1 true
  0  0 -1 -1  ----   0  0 true
  0  0 -1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  0 -1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  0  0 -1  ----   1  1 true
  0  0  0  0  ----   0  0 true
  0  0  0  1  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  0  1 -1  ----   1  1 true
  0  0  1  0  ----   1  1 true
  0  0  1  1  ----   0  0 true
  0  1 -1 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  1 -1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  1 -1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  1  0 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  1  0  0  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  1  0  1  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  1  1 -1  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  1  1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
  0  1  1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
  1 -1 -1 -1  ----   1  1 true
  1 -1 -1  0  ----   1 -1 false
  1 -1 -1  1  ----   1 -1 false
  1 -1  0 -1  ----   1  1 true
  1 -1  0  0  ----   1  1 true
  1 -1  0  1  ----   1 -1 false
  1 -1  1 -1  ----   1  1 true
  1 -1  1  0  ----   1  1 true
  1 -1  1  1  ----   1  1 true
  1  0 -1 -1  ----   1  1 true
  1  0 -1  0  ----   1 -1 false
  1  0 -1  1  ----   1 -1 false
  1  0  0 -1  ----   1  1 true
  1  0  0  0  ----   1  1 true
  1  0  0  1  ----   1 -1 false
  1  0  1 -1  ----   1  1 true
  1  0  1  0  ----   1  1 true
  1  0  1  1  ----   1  1 true
  1  1 -1 -1  ----   0  0 true
  1  1 -1  0  ----  -1 -1 true
  1  1 -1  1  ----  -1 -1 true
  1  1  0 -1  ----   1  1 true
  1  1  0  0  ----   0  0 true
  1  1  0  1  ----  -1 -1 true
  1  1  1 -1  ----   1  1 true
  1  1  1  0  ----   1  1 true
  1  1  1  1  ----   0  0 true
```

Comment: Yeah it was concluded they were different but still +1 for the detail, thank you